# Facebook ShareDialog - Name and Description not shown when posted from Android APP

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to integrate the Facebook with my Android App. I am using ShareDialog for sharing a short message using the below statements. The variable "message" the short information on game statistics. When I tried to share this particular message I am getting only the image and the Facebook app name. So finally I could see the image with the link and the Facebook app name but not with the values from (.setName / .setDescription). What I am supposed to do to get those details as well.

```
return new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
        .setPicture("http://i61.tinypic.com/jjbslv.png")
        .setName("Memory Game" + message)
        .setDescription(message) 
        .setLink("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free")
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer Source:
[Android Facebook SDK FacebookDialog.shareDialogBuilder doesn't show my description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416015/android-facebook-sdk-facebookdialog-sharedialogbuilder-doesnt-show-my-descripti?rq=1)

Replacing playstore's like with  website's link solved it for me too.