# Android Facebook SDK FacebookDialog.shareDialogBuilder doesn't show my description

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-share

I'm using the Facebook Android SDK to post a share from my Android app, setting the link to the Google Play url but I want to fill in my own description to be displayed.  My description shows up in my preview when I'm posting from my app, but when it gets displayed all that shows is "GET IT ON GOOGLE PLAY" and my description has disappeared.

I am modifying code taken from the [Facebook share tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share) included in the SDK (currently using version 3.19.0), here is the [ShareDialogBuilder](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder/) code:

```
private FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilderForLink() {
    return new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
            .setLink(webLink)
            .setName(getString(R.string.fb_name))
            .setDescription("Here is my description that I want included in the post.")
            .setPicture("http://www.website.com/images/icon.png");
}
```

Comment: We use the description from the og:desc tag that is on the url

Comment: @WizKid -- is there any way to override this?  Or is there somewhere else in the share that I can put my message?

Comment: @AlanMoore Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @WillCalderwood I linked to my own website instead of to Google Play and now it works fine!

Comment: @AlanMoore Thanks Alan, that was my plan for the day too. Glad you've confirmed that it works ok.

Answer (score 2):

I use Facebook SDK 4.0 and this method works fine

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {

                        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.share_onfacebook_title))
                                .setContentDescription(
                                        getString(R.string.share_onfacebook_message))
                                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.share_onfacebook_url)))
                                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.share_onfacebook_image_url)))
                                .build();

                        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
                    }
```

Comment: WHen I get a chance I'll update to 4.0 and give it a try, thanks!