# android facebook sdk v4 gets title and description from webpage

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

im using the following code to share from facebook:

```
        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taxipartner"))
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://s11.postimg.org/6d64we9nn/ic_launcher.png"))
                .setContentTitle("Join My Taxi")
                .setContentDescription(description)
                .build();



        shareDialog.show(linkContent);

    }
```

when im using that specific link (from google play) it fills the content and title automatically and not the what i configured..

when using other link website (such as https:/developers.facebook.com) its ok.

i looked on [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416015/android-facebook-sdk-facebookdialog-sharedialogbuilder-doesnt-show-my-descripti) and it they say it takes the desc from the metadata... how can i override this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on how the native apps render the app store links in the post. There was a bug report about this and is by design:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/626642064087460/

Bottom line is that for app store links(both iOS / Android), your metadata won't show up and it's rendered in a different way. This is by design.